# Simple examples of colored HOMFLY polynomial?

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, knot-theory

I'm trying to find some simple examples of using the colored HOMFLY polynomial and was wondering if anyone could give me a reference. I really only need an extremly basic definition of the colored HOMFLY polynomial and everything I'm finding on the internet is research level stuff. Lickorish's books mentions colored links only once in the last page of the chapter on calculating quantum invariants.

I'd really appreciate the reference link! Thanks!

Comment: Is the coloured HOMFLY polynomial of the [figure eight knot](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vohuan/Notes/Thesis.pdf), Chapter $5$, simple enough?

Comment: Thanks for finding this. It's probably as simple as I'm going to get.... Man, I feel like calculating the polynomial invariant for a knot is such a simple thing, is there really that much added complexity when calculating it's colored counterpart???